# Save the state of a page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I created a project where in the main page I have a random set of buttons that change their positions everytime i open the application. 
Clicking on each button, the user is redirected to different pages.

My problem is that I want to be redirected to the main page, without generating a new random set of buttons, whenever I leave one of the pages.

In other words, I want to save the same current order of buttons I have and retrieve it whenever I leave a page.
I tried using `await _navigation.PopAsync();` and it still gives me a new main page.

Comment: In what place do you generate your buttons?

Comment: If it suits you, you can save states of your buttons with "Application.Current.Properties" and get it when you navigates to the main page.